# Time conversion from 12 hours format to 24 hours format

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I wrote the following code to convert time from 12 hour format to 24 hours format. It works fine with simulator, but while using device it returns null.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat =@"hh:mm a";
NSString * endTimeString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"EndTime"]];
NSLog(@"Endtime from server responce:%@",endTimeString);
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:endTimeString];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm" ;
NSString *pmamDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Converted EndTime:%@ ",pmamDateString);
```

Comment: in here what the response u get --> Endtime from server responce:

Comment: i am getting time in 12hours format like 10:00 PM

Comment: We thought so. Can you show the exact string?

Comment: Printed strings while using simulator                                        ,Endtime from server responce:10:00 PM,                                        Converted EndTime:22:00,Printed  strings while using Device ,Endtime from server responce:10:00 PM, Converted EndTime:(null)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting locale on your `NSDateFormatter`:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
```

Comment: What is the timezone on your device?

Comment: This is working like charm for me. Could you please try resetting your device or maybe try in a different device?

Comment: Could you also test with locale `en_US` instead of `en_US_POSIX `.

Answer (score 0):

Hi friends ,

```
       Issue is with the device settings ,to resolve this issue i changed my device time format as "automatic" ,now its working fine with those settings change.
```